# Cómo limitar la cantidad de caracteres UTF-8

Tags: string

estoy utilizando la API de google geocoding para obtener latitud y longitud de direcciones, el problema es que es para usuarios japoneses, los cuales tienen caracteres "especiales" y cuando utilizo el servicio, la URL es demasiado larga

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%20%E3%80%92462-0825%20%E6%84%9B%E7%9F%A5%E7%9C%8C%20%E5%90%8D%E5%8F%A4%E5%B1%8B%E5%B8%82%E5%8C%97%E5%8C%BA%20%E5%A4%A7%E6%9B%BD%E6%A0%B9%EF%BC%93%E4%B8%81%E7%9B%AE%20%EF%BC%91%EF%BC%93-%EF%BC%92V-Hands%E3%83%93%E3%83%AB%201F&key=**APIKEY**

eso genera como resultado una respuesta ZERO_RESULTS

```
{
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

en cambio, si borro algunos caracteres, por ejemplo dejando la URL así

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%20%E3%80%92462-0825%20%E6%84%9B%E7%9F%A5%E7%9C%8C%20%E5%90%8D%E5%8F%A4%E5%B1%8B%E5%B8%82%E5%8C%97%E5%8C%BA%20%E5%A4%A7%E6%9B%BD%E6%A0%B9%EF%BC%93%E4%B8%81%E7%9B%AE%20%EF%BC%91%EF%BC%93&key=**APIKEY**

ahí sí obtengo los resultados que quiero, lo que busco es lograr que por ejemplo

```
$customerAddress = "日本 〒462-0825 愛知県 名古屋市北区 大曽根３丁目 １３-２V-Handsビル 1F"
```

no sobrepase la cantidad de caracteres UFT-8 admitidos por la URL, que al final termino armándola así

```
$geocodingUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$customerAddress&key=$apiKey";
```

no importa si elimino caracteres del final, pero necesito que la dirección no sea TAN específica para que pueda caber en la URL

[con esta herramienta podemos verificar lo que digo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview) al momento de colocar la dirección de ejemplo, recibimos ZERO_RESULTS hasta que borramos parte del texto

cómo podría hacerlo?

[aquí hay más documentación de la construcción de la URL](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/web-service-best-practices#BuildingURLs)

Comment: Yo lo que hago es mostrar los datos encriptados, siempre es más fácil así, podrías construir la url en el back y pasarla ya encriptada, de esa manera aumentas la privacidad y el espacio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diria que el problema no es la url demasiado larga, sino **algo de esa dirección le molesta**.

Según esa misma [documentación](https://developers.google.com/maps/url-encoding), las URL pasadas pueden tener un máximo de 8192 caracteres, y la url que les pasas ahora, sin la api key completa, es de tan solo 317 caraceres.

Jugando con la url en [esa página del geocode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview) donde aparece el error, he visto que dejando un espacio entre el 2 y V-hands se soluciona.

Es decir, en lugar de buscar esto:

```
日本 〒462-0825 愛知県 名古屋市北区 大曽根３丁目 １３-２V-Handsビル 1F
```

busca esto:

```
日本 〒462-0825 愛知県 名古屋市北区 大曽根３丁目 １３-２ V-Handsビル 1F
```

y verás que te devuelve la posición sin errores esta vez, y eso que aún es más larga debido al espacio agregado.

Mi japonés está muy oxidado, tanto que nunca lo he hablado ni entendido, pero diria que no les gusta mezclar esos numeros (que creo que se corresponden con un timbre o algo así) con la cadena de texto siguiente.

Comment: cierto, yo no sé absolutamente nada de japonés, así que asumía que era por la longitud de la URL, entonces esto no tendría una solución definita, solamente que el usuario debe escribir bien, no?

Comment: Exacto, a mi me pasa a veces con direcciones españolas mal escritas, es cuestion de saber corregirlas cuando suceda, pero en japones tendras que tirar del google translate, como yo he hecho, hasta darme cuenta de ese enganche entre esos numeros y la cadena de texto siguiente (y yo tampoco se nada de japonés, estaba bromeando)

Comment: el problema es que son muchas direcciones mal escritas y las estoy consumiendo desde una API, la solución que le voy a tener que dar hasta que los usuarios la corrijan será eliminar los números de sus direcciones si es que el geocoder de google no las procesa

```preg_replace('/\d+/u', '', $customerAddress);```

Comment: O asegurate de que hay espacios entre cadenas de numeros y de texto, como en esta ocasión, por si es algo comun entre ellos pegarlo todo aunque a efectos de maps o geocode les perjudique

Comment: utilizar api de google translate para las direcciones lo veo demasiado, al menos en este caso, no creo que añadirlo sería conveniente, de momento eliminar los números en esas direcciones fallidas o añadir espacios entre números y texto como dices será mejor, gracias!

Comment: de nada... :-)  no decia usar la api de google translate... tan solo estaba jugando con el para entender el porque esa dirección en concreto no funcionaba separando esos caracteres en lineas y juntandolos poco a poco por si veia algo raro, pues ya habia visto que no era por la cantidad de caracteres pues ibas sobrado